# applying function to each element in matrix --arrayfun

Tags: matlab, syntax

I'm trying to apply a function I wrote to each element in a matrix using arrayfun, but I'm either using the wrong function or getting my syntax wrong.

I've written a function with 3 inputs, 1 output and saved it to an m file in the same directory.  I'd like to call that function, with 1 input being an element in the matrix and the 2 remaining inputs being set, and get an output matrix.

My code looks like:

```
fun = @(x) my_function(x,input2,input3);
B = arrayfun(@(x) fun, A)
```

I get the following error

```
Error using arrayfun function_handle output type is not currently implemented.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
B = arrayfun(fun, A);
```

because `fun` is already a handle to your [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Note that variables `input1`, `input2` have to be defined *before* you define your function. The values of those variables get ["hard-wired" into the function definition](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621). If you later change those variables, that will have no effect on the function.